# Insert the to_timestamp and NLS_LANGUAGE through unix shell

Tags: oracle, insert, ksh, unix-timestamp, nls-lang

I've got this timestamp field:

```
    if [ "${arr[1]}" != "NUMBER" ];
    then
        fieldtmst=`echo $var | 
            awk 'BEGIN { f="'"'"'" }
            {
               split($0,x,/@#/);
               printf    "%s\n", f x[1] f
            }'`
    else
        fieldtmst=`echo $var |
            awk '{ split($0,x,"@#"); print x[1]}'`   
    fi
```

Well this code needs me to make an insert; when i write the insert this part of code recognize if the field i'm going to insert is a `NUMBER` or not and if is not `NUMBER` this field will be insert with quotes (something like: `'fieldtmst'`) and if is `NUMBER` (`fieldtmst`) without quotes..Ok, now i have a problem. I have to implement in this code that if is timestamp will be write with quotes of course, and with `to_timestamp` and the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American`. So the output of that field will be something like:

```
to_timestamp('02-JAN-13 01.06.00.000000 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF6 AM','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'),
```

Understand? Thanks

Comment: Yeah would be very simple in that way :) but is an dynamic insert.. It's all automated so i have to make the check for every field to know  what kind of data_type it is. But if it's a `date` or `timestamp` i must insert in some way the `to_date` or `to_timestamp` in that field and the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American` because without them i get errors.

Comment: That still doesn't explain what the problem is, unless I'm missing something. You've said what you want to do, not why you can't do it. What have you tried, and what doesn't work?

Comment: in the if condition i posted i want implement that if that field is data or timestamp write it `fieldtmst=`echo $var | awk 'BEGIN {` `f="'"'"'" } {split($0,x,/@#/); printf "%s\n", f xTO_DATE(here before` `the result of field for example)[1] f}'` ` hope you understand now.